# Cannot set property of null in angular-2 when using this?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I'm getting an error in

> angular2-polyfills.js:143 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'singlehotel' of null(…)

and a warning from Firebase

> FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot set property 'singlehotel' of null

When I tried to get the data from Firebase I am getting this error, any one please help to to resolve this.

Thanks in advance!

### here is my code

```
ngAfterContentInit() {

       this.singlehotel = {};
       firebase.database().ref('Rests/').once('value', function(snapshot) {
         console.log('value from db' + JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()));
         var getrest = snapshot.val();
         console.log(JSON.stringify(getrest));

           for (var key in getrest) {

                  if(restemail == getrest[key].email){

          console.log(key + ':' + JSON.stringify(getrest[key]));
                          this.singlehotel = getrest[key]; //getting error here when using this

         }         
            }
         });                
      };
```

### index.html

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      // for security reasons i am hiding my keys 
      var config = {
        apiKey: "***",
        authDomain: "***",
        databaseURL: "***",
        storageBucket: "**",
        messagingSenderId: "**"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>
       <body>
      <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    </body>
```

### view

```
<div class="container" style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">
    <h1><b>Hotel Name :{{singlehotel.displayName}}</b></h1>
</div>
```

both belongs to same componet.when the view gets loaded the ngAfterContentInit() function willi be called every time , thats how the function triggers but i am not able to store in scope i mean this.please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` doesn't point to the current class instance if you use `function() {... }`. Use arrow functions instead

```
firebase.database().ref('Rests/').once('value', (snapshot) => {
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: thanks it solved the issue, but the view is not updating even after the data arrived from the firebase . it is getting updating after approx  10-13 seconds.i want to update the view soon after the data arrived from firebase. thanks!

Comment: Where do you initialize `firebase`? It sounds like it's running outside Angulars zone. If this can't be fixed by initializing firebase inside Angular, you can use `zone.run(...)` to make code called by firebase (callbacks passed to firebase like event handlers) execute again inside Angulars zone or call `ChangeDetectorRef`s `detectChanges()` after the properties were updated.

Comment: i have initialized my firebase in the index.html. i didn't get what you are exactly saying? the data is retrieving from firebase and also i printed on my console.

Comment: Angular2 uses zone.js to figure out when it has to run change detection. Code that runs outside Angulars zone pervents Angular from recognizing that. As solution you either have to initialize your firebase library inside Angular to make it run inside Angulars zone or alternatively invoke change detection yourself.

Comment: ho thanks for reply! i understood the problem . actually i am very new to angular-2, can you tell me how to  initialize your firebase library inside Angular to make it run inside Angulars zone ?if you need i will share my index file where i initialized my firebase.

Comment: Yes, please share some code. I don't know firebase.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127172/discussion-between-sukumar-dhoni-and-gunter-zochbauer).